# Include Hyperlink (with _blank target) property inside NgbTooltip content

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a requirement with the NgbTooltip,

- the tooltip should allow to include a hyperlink with "_blank" target. ex: Learn more
- the tooltip should hide when clicked on the document body.

Below is my approach, and doesn't work as expected.

```
<a [ngbTooltip]="hintTooltip" tabindex="0"  triggers="click:blur">hint</a>
<ng-template #hintTooltip>
  Sample hint description
  <a href="www.abc.com" target="_blank">Learn more</a>
</ng-template>
```

the above code opens the tooltip by showing the hyperlink. but when I click the hyperlink, instead of opening a new window, it hides the tooltip.

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viipeo-dqjmfh?file=app/tooltip-triggers.html

Appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: it is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viipeo

Comment: thanks mate... but i need to hide the tooltip on outside of the tooltip click as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, If anyone is interested, below is the solution

.html

```
<a [ngbTooltip]="hintTooltip" tabindex="0"  triggers="click:blur">hint</a>
    <ng-template #hintTooltip>
      Sample hint description
      <a href="www.abc.com" target="_blank" (click)="nToolTip(t1, 'http://www.google.com');">Learn more</a>
    </ng-template>
```

.ts

```
_toolTipCollection = [];
nToolTip(tooltip, _url?: string): void {
    if (tooltip.isOpen()) {
        if (_url) {
            window.open(_url, '_blank');
        }
    }
    for (const tooltip of this._toolTipCollection) {
        tooltip.close();
    }
    this._toolTipCollection = [];

    tooltip.toggle();
    this._toolTipCollection.push(tooltip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewChild to get reference to the Element then use tooltip method to close

```
 @ViewChild('ref') ref;
  @HostListener('mouseleave',['$event']) onHoverOutside(){
   this.ref.close();
  }
```

Example:https:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viipeo

Comment: hostlistener works for component, but not the for an element as i know. so in my page, the tool is closed only on body mouseleave.